# Is it possible to change the index owner from User1 to User2 while connected as User1?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to change the index owner from User1 to User2?
I need to create index from User1 connection but with  index owner = User2 for table from User2 tablespace. 
May be there is an aportunity to create an index with direct determination of index owner?

Thank you!

Comment: The table space is just where the segment is stored, it has nothing to do with the owner of the table or the index.

Comment: You can't change the owner of a database object. You have to drop and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, USER1 must have the `INDEX` on the `TABLE` privilege. So, give the `GRANT` from USER2 or other  admin user using this, if it is not already done.

```
GRANT INDEX ON USER2.table_name  TO  USER1;
```

Then, by logging in as USER1, you could create an INDEX owned by USER2 like this.

```
CREATE INDEX USER2.index_name  ON   USER2.table_name (column1);
```